# Check for trailing \ in string returned from msoFileDialogFolderPicker, Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

I am using the msoFileDialogFolderPicker to return a path when a user wants to deposit a report in a specific folder.

A custom form (ufSelRepType) shows up in the macro in cases where the default save location already has an output file or when the user does not wish to save to the default location. The custom form specifies a few common report save locations and gives the option to select an alternate location. Clicking button cmdCustom does the following:

```
Private Sub cmdCustom_Click()
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    Me.Tag = CurDir
    Me.Hide

End Sub
```

The code in the macro to handle the form output is simple:

```
 strSavePath = ufSelRepType.Tag
```

Selecting a folder, the string is always returned without a trailing "\". However, if a drive root is selected (we use mapped drives to our file server and so while this case may be rare, it is not an inconcievable scenario) the string returned ends with a "\".

How might I go about checking for the trailing "\" and handling it?

UPDATE: Per solution below, this is the new code for the form control cmdCustom:

```
Private Sub cmdCustom_Click()
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    'Getting save folder
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
    strFolderPath = CurDir

    'Checking that path ends in \
    If Right(strFolderPath, 1) = "\" Then
        GoTo Complete
    Else:
        strFolderPath = strFolderPath & "\"
        GoTo Complete
    End If
Exit Sub

Complete:
    Me.Tag = strFolderPath
    Me.Hide
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `strSavePath` is just a string then you can check if `"\"` is the right-most character:

```
If Right(strSavePath, 1) = "\" Then
  doSomething()
Else
  doSomethingElse()
End If
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for this. The syntax of Right is Right(string, <integer number of characters to check>)?

Comment: @music2myear - yes, the syntax is `Right(string, length)` where `length`: _Required; Variant (Long). Numeric expression indicating how many characters to return. If 0, a zero-length string ("") is returned. If greater than or equal to the number of characters in string, the entire string is returned._

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've implemented it on the form itself because the form is used in a couple places in the macro and doing it there prevented code duplication. Works like a charm.